# tcolorbox: \newtcbtheorem referencing

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, tcolorbox

Using `\newtcbtheorem`, how do we reference the created environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{exa}{example}{Example}
\Crefname{exa}{Example}{Example}
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = section]
{Example}{Exam\smash{p}le}{%                                                        
  breakable,
  fonttitle = \bfseries,
  colframe = blue!75!black,
  colback = blue!10
}{exa}
\begin{document}
\begin{Example}{Example}{exam}
  Some example
\end{Example}
\noindent
\Cref{exa:exam}
\end{document}
```

Using `tcbmaketheorem`, I used `\newcounter{exa}`, but I can't get referencing to work here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define the format for the new object; in this case, for `tcb@cnt@Example`, using something like

```
\crefformat{tcb@cnt@Example}{example~#2#1#3}
\Crefformat{tcb@cnt@Example}{Example~#2#1#3}
```

or any other format you want. A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\crefformat{tcb@cnt@Example}{example~#2#1#3}
\Crefformat{tcb@cnt@Example}{Example~#2#1#3}
\makeatother
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = section]
{Example}{Exam\smash{p}le}{%                                                        
  breakable,
  fonttitle = \bfseries,
  colframe = blue!75!black,
  colback = blue!10
}{exa}
\begin{document}
\begin{Example}{Example}{exam}
  Some example
\end{Example}
\noindent
\Cref{exa:exam} and~\cref{exa:exam}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The correct name to be used in `\Crefformat`, and `\crefformat` can be obtained from one of the warnings obtained in the original code using `\Cref` without the proper definitions:

```
LaTeX Warning: Cref reference format for label type `tcb@cnt@Example' undefined on input line 21.
```

Answer (score 8):

Since `tcolorbox` version 2.41 (2013/07/23), there is integrated support for the `cleveref` package. You just have to move `\crefname` and `\Crefname` as options into `\newtcbtheorem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = section,
  crefname={example}{Example},
  Crefname={Example}{Example} ]
{Example}{Exam\smash{p}le}{%
  breakable,
  fonttitle = \bfseries,
  colframe = blue!75!black,
  colback = blue!10
}{exa}
\begin{document}
\begin{Example}{Example}{exam}
  Some example
\end{Example}
\noindent
\Cref{exa:exam} and~\cref{exa:exam}.
\end{document}
```

The output is identical to that of the solution of Gonzalo Medina.

Comment: Thank you twice! I was disliking the inconsistent title heights very much with tcolorbox theorems, and couldn't find any way to just stop making them larger for the hangers/drops/idk what to call them. `\smash` does the trick. Unfortunately, it had to be a trick...

Answer (score 5):

As of 2020-09-08, the previous offered solutions do not work anymore. The cleveref 4.31 (2020-07-31) documentation provides an example and solution to this problem on page 372: the label type optional argument is used to feed cleveref with the needed name information.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtcbtheorem{example}{Example}{label type=example}{exa}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}{title}{label}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
\end{example}
Checking if \textbf{cleveref} works: \cref{exa:label} and \Cref{exa:label}.

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE results]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Seems label type is limited too few possibility (and english possibility). If I change example by exemple (french word), it doesn't work anymore.