# Autoref numbering different from numbering displayed in theorem itself

Tags: newtheorem, autoref

I am facing the problem that the numbering for defined tcbtheorem is numbered correctly in the tcbtheorem environment itself, but that autoref typically displayes a different number, or gets stuck in the numbering.

A small example is as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
    % General document formatting
    \usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
    \usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    
    % hyperref & url package
    \usepackage[
    hidelinks
    ]{hyperref}
    \usepackage{bookmark}
    \usepackage{url}
    
    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
    \newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within=chapter, number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}}]{definition}{Definition}{}{def}
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand\definitionautorefname{Definition}
    \makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
%
\section{First Section}
%
We state in \autoref{def:life} an attitude.
%
\begin{definition}{Life\label{def:life}}
    _Life is fun.
\end{definition}
%
We state in \autoref{def:work} a fact.
%
\begin{definition}{Work\label{def:work}}
    _Work is a necessity.
\end{definition}
\section{Second Section}
%
%
We state in \autoref{def:latex} a truth.
%
\begin{definition}{Latex\label{def:latex}}
    _Latex is not so much fun.
\end{definition}
%
\end{document}
```

When compiled, the the example shows that the numbering in the autoref is off, and it seems to be stuck to the section.
The numbering in the definition environment is correct (cf. picture below)
[image: False Autoref Numbering for Self-Defined Environment]

What can I do that the autoref references the definition using the number stated in the corresponding environment?

Best regards,
Alex

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132297/tcolorbox-newtcbtheorem-referencing ?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong input syntax (and you should have get a warning in the log about the labels `def_` you are producing). The new environment has *two* mandatory arguments where the second will build the label:

```
\documentclass{book}
    % General document formatting
    \usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
    \usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    % hyperref & url package
    \usepackage[
    hidelinks
    ]{hyperref}
    \usepackage{bookmark}
    \usepackage{url}

    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
    \newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within=chapter, number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}}]{definition}{Definition}{}{def}
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand\definitionautorefname{Definition}
    \makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
%
\section{First Section}
%
We state in \autoref{def:life} an attitude.
%
\begin{definition}{Life}{life}
    Life is fun.
\end{definition}
%
We state in \autoref{def:work} a fact.
%
\begin{definition}{Work}{work}
    Work is a necessity.
\end{definition}
\section{Second Section}
%
%
We state in \autoref{def:latex} a truth.
%
\begin{definition}{Latex}{latex}
    Latex is not so much fun.
\end{definition}
%
\end{document}
```